# Invalid expression pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

For example String is `'10S#9D7T*'`.
My desire result is 3 arrays. `[('10S#'), ('9D'), ('7T*')]`

There are 3 condition.

1. First one or two digit range is 0~10 always.
2. And follow one character is located always.
3. And follow `'#'` or `'*'`. But it is not essential.

That is my code.

```
rex = re.compile(r'\d?\d\w?[\*\#]')
str = '10S#9D7T'
print(rex.findall(str))
```

Acutal Result -> `['10S#']`

There is only one array.

please fixed my regex pattern.

Comment: Your example string does not contain a `*`, and `[*#]` does not have a `?` after so you enforce one of these after the match. Just add a `*` in your string and a `?` after the `[*#]`. Note you do not need to escape the `*` in the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can get three results by making the `[*#]` class optional. (Also, note that those characters don't need to be escaped.)

```
str = '10S#9D7T*'
rex = re.compile(r'\d?\d\w?[*#]?')
print(rex.findall(str))
```

Result: `['10S#', '9D', '7T*']`

As for your second rule, "And follow one character is located always," you probably want to make the `\w` non-optional by removing the `?` directly after it.

```
r'\d?\d\w[*#]?'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change `\d?\d` to `\d{1,2}` and as the following character is always there it should not be optional so you could omit the question mark. The * and # do not have to be escaped in the character class and add a quesion mark to that to make it optional.

You might use:

```
\d{1,2}\w[*#]?
```

That will match:

- `\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits
- `\w` Match a word character
- `[*#]?` Optional character class to match one of * or #

  import re
  str = "10S#9D7T*"
  rex = re.compile(r'\d{1,2}[A-Z][*#]?')
  print(rex.findall(str))

Result

```
['10S#', '9D', '7T*']
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WLe8RN/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/g3jZR9)